# How to install KDevelop 5 on Red Hat 7

Tags: linux, redhat, kdevelop

I'd like to see how KDevelop 5 works. I have a RedHat 7 machine where I am a regular user (not root) and try to build KDevelop from sources. I've looked at the list of required software and found that I need **kdelibs-devel** as one of dependencies. Unfortunately, I cannot find such a packages. There are too many small bundles on the KDE site and nothing named **kdelibs-devel**.

Can anybody advise?

Is there a simpler way to build KDevelop5?

Regards,

Michael

Comment: Red Hat 7 is 16 years old. Do you mean RHEL 7?

Answer (score 4):

For the final 5.0 release, we now provide an AppImage which you can just download and run without compiling anything. It should work, if not, let us know.

Check out: https://www.kdevelop.org/download

Comment: on RHEL 7.3 libfuse.so.2 is missing